# resumable bash sessions with branch maintenance

Tags: linux, bash, git, session, bashrc

Is there a utility that streamlines the storing and restoring of bash sessions?  I'd like to be able to do EG

```
$ KUNG=pao
$ foo commit  # saves the current environment
              # as an anonymous changeset from the previous savepoint
$ SCHNICKENS="What's up, doc?"
$ SCHNICKENS="$(echo Schmoove)"
$ unset KUNG
$ foo diff HEAD  # outputs a $(set) of commands
                 # which comprise the current changeset
unset KUNG;
SCHNICKENS="Schmoove"
$ foo branch edit-su-question  # creates a new branch with that name
$ foo merge master  # updates the current environment
                    # with any changes made to ~/.bashrc
                    # since it was branched or last merged
$ function fierce_fist_of_foo {
      cut -f 2 | xargs -I {} bash foo {} '>>' ffof.out;
  }
$ foo checkout master  # switches current branch
                       # to the one checked out by ~/.bashrc
$ foo commit -m "learned the fierce_fist_of_foo technique"
  # new interactive `bash` invocations now load that function
```

Given its similarity to the `git` command-set, I'm tempted to use an obscene word, or alternatively a Smashing Pumpkins album title, as the command name in this example.  But good ole `foo` it is.

I'm basing my faith in the workability of this concept largely on the presumption that running `set` from a bash shell will give you an invokable script which will restore that environment.  I'm not sure if this is entirely true.

*Anyway*, is there something out there that works like this?  Extra points if it actually uses `git` as part of its implementation.  Like, I'll accept that answer.  Since you're only in it for the points and all.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure one could come up with something using `env` and `source`.

```
 # "commit"
 env > saved_state

 # "checkout"
 source saved_state
```

Everything else would be interface sugar. One could even script putting the `saved_state` files in some git repository somewhere automatically so one could browse it with `tig`.

I have to admit I am horrified of the potential for extremely messy and confusing workflows this would allow.

Comment: hmm, maybe it would be that simple.  Though if you use `env` you won't get any function definitions, or some other things that I'm not sure of.  Also the checkout would have to do `unset`s for `-` lines in the diff.  I was imagining parsing the output from `set` and building the set of assignments, `unset`s, `function` statements, etc. that would be necessary to invoke that change.  Other things like `shopt` should be included, too.

Comment: As for it being messy and confusing: I was hoping to find something like this to enable avoiding messy and confusing workflows where I have to source and then update a script by piping `history` into vim and copying the function definitions out of the history into the script.  It makes way more sense to do it with prototyping of the shell environment.

Comment: @intuited Yes, this doesn't work for functions. Maybe what you really want is a convenient way to store snippets instead of this putting your whole workflow thourgh some VC machinery?

Comment: Keeping snippets under version control, with task-oriented branches, seems to me to be the most convenient way to store them.  `git` is actually a bit limited as a working model or implementation base, for two reasons: 1) the branch set is a flat list, meaning that you don't have a convenient way to [re-]organize a lot of them;  2) there's no way to create a "layered branch" that dynamically merges more than one branch.  In programming terms, branches are static types, and commits are compiles.